# Equivalent of C++ variadic templates in Java

Tags: java

I wish to write a generic type safe observer in Java. In C++, I can easily do it by using variadic template from c++11, like following:

```
class Observer<typename... T>
{
    void update(T... args);
};
```

Now, in java, the best I could do is:

```
class Observer<T>
    {
        void update(T args);
    };
```

Now, update can not take multiple arguments of different types like in C++. Could someone suggest a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. Why not use `void update(T... args);` ?

Comment: Not all args are necessarily of the same type in his use case.

Answer (score 4):

If all the arguments extend/implement T you can say:

```
class Observer<T>{
        void update(List<? extends T> args){}
}
```

Comment: This would only allow `List<T>` rather than subtypes. Say, for example, `T` is `Number`; this construct would not allow a `List<Integer>` as a parameter. I would say `List<? extends T>` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is creating class like tuple, so you don't use variadic form, but group args beforehand. However, this answer depends heavily on usage scenario.
There is no one-to-one analog.